# Attribute aliasing using __setattr__ in Python

Tags: python, getattr, setattr

I have a Python class which has various internal variables that I want to expose as x, y, a simple example being:

```
class Vec2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [0.0, 0.0]
        self.mapping = {'x':0, 'y':1}

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.data[index] = value

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.mapping:
            return self.data[self.mapping[key]]
        else:
            raise AttributeError

    def _setattr__(self, key, value):
        # ?????
        pass
```

I would have thought that this would not work because `__getattr__` accesses members of self. However, everything works as long as I don't try to define a `__setattr__` - even if I just make it equal to `pass`, I get recursion. How should I implement `__setattr__`? In particular, what should I be calling in the case that they key is not x or y?

Also, in general my question is whether this the right way of implementing the desired behavior such as:

```
v = Vec2()
# this
v.x = 1.0
v.y = 0.0
# or this
v[0] = 1.0
v[1] = 0.0
```

or whether there are better alternatives. I'm using python 2.7.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `__getattr__` or `__setattr__` for this. [Properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) are a better fit for your task:

```
# Inherit from object. This is important.
class Vec2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [0.0, 0.0]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, val):
        self.data[index] = val

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.data[0]
    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        self.data[0] = val

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.data[1]
    @y.setter
    def y(self, val):
        self.data[1] = val
```

The problem with your `__setattr__` attempts is that `__setattr__` is called for all attribute assignments, including `self.data`, `self.mapping`, and any assignments you attempt in `__setattr__` itself. You can fix that by delegating to `object.__setattr__` for attributes other than `x` or `y`, but properties are easier. Properties also save you from having to use `object.__getattribute__` for attribute access in `__getattr__`, which was one of the factors contributing to your infinite recursion problems.

In contrast to `__setattr__`, properties only trigger when you try to access the attribute they control. An `x` property doesn't have to deal with accesses to attributes other than `x`, and you don't have to use alternative attribute access mechanisms when writing a property.

Comment: When I try adding these, it does not do anything. That is if I try using `v.x=1.0` it just adds a attribute called `x` to the class and does not call your properties. If I put a print statement in these methods, it does not print anything. Do I need to do something else. Based on the page you linked to it should work but so far I'm still having problems.

Comment: OK I found the problem, I need to derive the class from object for this to work.

Comment: @Robotbugs: Yep. Most of the fancy stuff doesn't work unless a class has `object` somewhere in its ancestry.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `object.__setattr__` explicitly to avoid recursion:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    object.__setattr__(self, key, value)
```